# Accidentally cleared ~/.bash_profile contents (Mac)

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I accidentally used `>` to put an output inside `~/.bash_profile` and ended up erasing a lot of configs I had saved there.

I need help to recover it. I still have iTerm opened with all the `~/.bash_profile` old settings before erase active. Which means next time I close it or do source `~/.bash_profile` all the settings will be lost forever.

Is there a way to recover the current `~/.bash_profile` settings loaded? Or something?

Comment: `Time Machine` maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Normally, `.bashrc` is a copy from `/etc/skel`, so you can restore it from there.

If you added some extra informations in this file, you still have them available in your current session. To recover those, say:

- `env` to see those variables.
- `typeset -f` to see the functions that are defined.

Comment: env solved by problem. As for /etc/skel , I don't have that in mac. Thanks

Comment: Nice to read that ; ) I [read](http://superuser.com/a/163555/204979) that the equivalent of `/etc/skel` in OSX might be `/System/Library/User\ Template/English.lproj`. Can you check so?